# How to construct url path with two detailview

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have following url patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='forum'),
    path('category/<int:pk>/', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='forum-detail'),
]
```

Inside the CategoryDetailView  I will list the posts related to that category. So, when I click the any of the post I want the post detail view inside the category, because when I will create post with CreateView class I want category already predefined. I could also do the following

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', ForumPostDetailView.as_view(), name='forum-post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', ForumPostCreateView.as_view(), name='forum-post-create'),
]
```

In this case user should choose the category by himself when he or she will try to create the post. But I want the category to be chosen already something like this ( I know this is wrong)

```
path('category/<int:pk>/post/<int:pk>/', ForumPostDetailView.as_view(), name='forum-post-detail'),
    path('category/<int:pk>/post/new/', ForumPostCreateView.as_view(), name='forum-post-create'),
]
```

my view file and models are like this:

```
class ForumPostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PostForum
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    template_name = 'forum/forum_post_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class Category(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default='category.png', upload_to='category_pics')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class PostForum(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So how to do it? Now it shows

```
IntegrityError
null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the category.id in urls.py

```
path('category/<int:cat_id>/post/new/', ForumPostCreateView.as_view(), name='forum-post-create')
```

check if it exists in your view

```
class ForumPostCreateView(CreateView):
    category = None

    def despatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().despatch(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'cat_id' in self.kwargs:
            self.category = Category.objects.get(id=cat_id)
```

Now you can use it in your form when you initialise the form

Comment: still shows IntegrityError at /forum/category/1/post/new/
null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: That's because you're passing a null category_id.  You need 2 urls.  One for with and one for without a category_id